# Software caused connection abort

Tags: android, sockets

I've seen that there is tons of posts like this, but couldn't find one that helps me.

I've read in one of them that this a generic error, and it depends on what you are doing.

In my case, I've created a socket, got its input and output stream and use the output to send some data. The strange thing is that I can send things and the server receives them. But I get this error pretty often. Like, once every 5 minutes.

Don't know if might help, but at first I had the soTimeout of the socket as 10 seconds. After reading some articles, I've increased it to 1 minute.

Don't know if I can add code that helps, because I litterally have the error when I do

```
output.write(byte[])
```

but if you think it might be something I could add, feel free to ask

Thanks in advance

Comment: I also have this Exception and it occurs randomly. Do you have any solution?

Comment: Kind of. I ended up rewriting some stuff, but couldn't find exactly what it was :/